# Daisy chaining lights with I2C

Tags: arduino, i2c, lighting

I want to make some modular mood lighting. The idea is that there is one master in the chain (the one that gets turned on first) and the other lights can plug in to each other. Each light has a rotary encoder to adjust the color. What I want to do is:

1. Have the first light check for a master on the chain, if there is none, it becomes the master.
2. If there is a master, request an address from the master (maybe begin with an address of 255, then send a request for a new address to the master)
3. The master sends the desired color to the slaves, each time it changes.

I'm having trouble trying to make the other devices find the master on the chain. Is there some smart, if any, way to do it? If there isn't, is there another way/protocol with which it could be done?

Comment: You can't autonomously request something from a master, you have to wait for an invitation to make a request.

Comment: Well, a device can't check if there is a master, unless it tries to be the master, or wait unless it sees that there is no communication on bus and the decides to be the master. And it can't request an address unless it already has an address, and it can't request anything unless it is a master again. Perhaps simply make the devices have a timeout and become master if no transmissions are seen, and make all slaves be at same address so color can be broadcasted. Do they even need separate addresses?

Comment: Instead of I2C addresses, you should look at how the WS2812, APA102C and other chainable RGB LEDs work. They use the chain sequence as the address. You could also select the master by detecting whether the module is first in the chain (no other module connected to the input side)

Comment: But if you do it your way: just make the master address 0 or something. When it turns on, your device sends a message to address 0 and looks for ACK. If it gets an ACK, there's already a master.

Comment: @Justme That's a pretty good idea, making them all the same address. Then I'd just  need to make the master send something, say every second and if there hasn't been sent something for like 5 seconds, there is no master. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just make any one that sees its encoder changed by the user announce that to everyone else?  You could do an open collector bus and self monitoring for collision detection, if you want to repeat the message automatically.  If you see a collision backoff a random time and repeat.  If you see an actual message from someone else, cease being the master.  Have each broadcast include a count of how many have been sent since actual user interaction, in a conflict whoever has the lower since user interaction number wins and everyone else stops sending.